# ¿Cómo puedo detectar si cambia la URL con javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

¿Cómo podría saber cuándo la ruta o la `URL` cambia usando `javascript`? Por ejemplo, algún evento que se dispare cuando se cambia la url actual.

```
//Por ejemplo algún listener que permita ejecutar una función al detectar algún cambio.
document.addEventListener('algunevento', function(){}, false);
```

¿Alguna idea?

Comment: Si la Url cambia esta misma se puede ver reflejada en el codebehind ya que para que cambie tiene que pasar por el evento Load de la pagina y desde ahí mandarla al clientside

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El evento se llama `onhaschange`:

```
document.addEventListener('onhaschange', function(){}, false);
```

Cabe aclarar que hay que verificar si el *browser* lo soporta:

```
if("onhaschange" in window){
   // sí lo soporta
}
```

Comment: esto es solo si contiene `#` hash en la url

Answer (score 0):

Si estas hablando de la url que aparece en el navegador, esa url se encuentra en la variable window.location.href a partir de ahí tienes una serie de eventos para controlar que alguien sale de la página, si es lo que quieres saber, no me queda claro cual es el objetivo.

Mira aquí a ver si es lo que estas buscando :

- [Unload](https://api.jquery.com/unload/)
- [onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload)

Comment: Gracias por responder,  aldanux eso era justamente lo que buscaba.